# want to send deltas to server using ra-data-json-server

Tags: rest, reducers, react-admin

we're using react-admin with a jsonServerRestClient from ra-data-json-server.  We've encapsulated it to handle GET_MANY a little differently, so we already have a touchpoint there to control what goes to the server.

Going forward we would like to be able to send a delta of changes when an item is modified, as some items (in our case, groups) have 4k+ members in them.

While we could save the raw objects to local storage when they come into our REST client and use that info to create a delta upon save, the state and reducers should have that info already somewhere else, right?

So what files should I look at to see how to modify what gets sent to the REST client during modify events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, React-Admin actually is nice enough to give us the previous version of whatever data it wants to save. When you're writing a restClient you will be given type, resource and params.  Inside params is both params.data and params.previousData. You can do your deltas there, comparing both.